# MySQL - how to order by name a to z but put empty name on the bottom?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have in the table firstname, lastname, mobile. which is represented in scroll list with "firstname lastname"

```
SELECT * FROM `sh_contact` order by firstname asc;
```

but some of the rows contain empty firstname as a result the scroll list shows empty `"      lastname".`

to avoid user interface confusion. how to put all the non empty firstname on top and at the end show empty firstnames?

Comment: Put `CASE WHEN` in your `ORDER BY` and assign `ZZZ...Z` to empty ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple keys:

```
order by (case when firstname = '' or firstname is null then 1 else 2 end) desc,
         firstname asc
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `sh_contact` ORDER BY CASE WHEN firstname = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, firstname
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q2Pt13yHCX638QsdqZW7Tc/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
order by firstname is null, firstname
```

This works because in MySQL, boolean expressions that are true are `1` and false are `0`, so sorting by that will put all null firstnames last.

If you want to treat blanks as nulls, use this:

```
...
order by coalesce(firstname, '') = '', firstname
```

Or if firstname is never null, even simpler:

```
...
order by firstname = '', firstname
```